# How to plot values for a subgroup based on time in R?

Tags: r

So currently I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    yearMon       V1
1   012011 2.534161
2   012012 1.818421
3   012013 1.635179
4   012014 1.609195
5   012015 1.794979
6   022011 3.408389
7   022012 1.756303
8   022013 1.577855
9   022014 1.511905
10  022015 1.748879
11  032011 2.664336
12  032012 1.912023
13  032013 1.408602
14  032014 1.646091
15  032015 1.705069
16  042011 2.532895
17  042012 3.342926
18  042013 3.056657
```

I want to plot the averages for a certain month every year, IE the averages for March 2011, March 2012, March 2013, March 2014 all in one graph, and repeat this for each of the 12 months. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I would recommend that you split your first column in years and months. Then you can use Month column as factor for stat_summary to plot mean by group. Alternatively, you can calculate the mean somewhere else by factor (search for aggregate) and then make a ggplot with the new data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) monthplot** Convert the data to zoo (using `"yearmon"` class -- we also show in the comments an alternative converter) and then to `"ts"` class and then use `monthplot` (in the base of R) with the `"ts"` object (or further below we use `autoplot.zoo` (which uses the ggplot2 package) with the zoo object).

```
library(zoo)

# to_yearmon <- function(x) as.yearmon((x %% 10000) + (x %/% 10000 - 1) / 12)
to_yearmon <- function(x) as.yearmon(sub("(.*)(....)$", "\\2-\\1", x))
ser_zoo <- read.zoo(ser_df, FUN = to_yearmon) # convert to DF to zoo
ser_ts <- as.ts(ser_zoo) # convert zoo to ts
monthplot(ser_ts)
```

(continued after plot)

[image: screenshot]

**2) autoplot.zoo** We show how to plot (i) one line per year (2011, 2012, ...) all in one chart and (ii) in separate panels and (iii) one line per month (1, 2, 3, ...) all in one chart and (iv) separate panels.

We create a data frame `ser_df2` with 3 columns representing month, year and the value of the series.  Then we convert this long form series to a wide form, `ser_zoo2` with with times 1, 2, 3, ... representing the months and one column per year.  We also convert this long form series to a wide form, `ser_zoo2`, with times 2011, 2012, ... representing years and one column per month.  By plotting each of these in a single panel and in multiple panels we get 2x2 = 4 charts which we show below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

ser_df2 <- data.frame(month = cycle(ser_zoo), 
                      year = floor(as.numeric(time(ser_zoo))), 
                      ser = coredata(ser_zoo))

ser_zoo2 <- read.zoo(ser_df2, index = 1, split = 2) # split into one column per year
p1 <- autoplot(ser_zoo2, facet = NULL)
p2 <- autoplot(ser_zoo2)

ser_zoo3 <- read.zoo(ser_df2, index = 2, split = 1) # split into one column per month
p3 <- autoplot(ser_zoo3, facet = NULL)
p4 <- autoplot(ser_zoo3)

grid.arrange(p1, p3, p2, p4, ncol = 2)
```

(click on chart to enlarge)

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** We used this as the input data frame `ser_df`:

```
Lines <- "
    yearMon       V1
1   012011 2.534161
2   012012 1.818421
3   012013 1.635179
4   012014 1.609195
5   012015 1.794979
6   022011 3.408389
7   022012 1.756303
8   022013 1.577855
9   022014 1.511905
10  022015 1.748879
11  032011 2.664336
12  032012 1.912023
13  032013 1.408602
14  032014 1.646091
15  032015 1.705069
16  042011 2.532895
17  042012 3.342926
18  042013 3.056657
"


ser_df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it more explicitly with ggplot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)
library(lubridate)


data %>%
  mutate(date = 
           yearMon %>%
           parse_date_time("%m%y"),
         month = 
           date %>%
           format("%B") %>%
           ordered(month.name),
         year = 
           date %>%
           format("%Y") %>%
           as.numeric) %>%
  ggplot +
  aes(x = year, y = V1, color = month) + 
  geom_line()
```